# How to position Google Map Marker?

Tags: java, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a custom marker with a label I want to position the label in the center of the marker. I tried padding, margin and offset still it wont work. How can I do it?
[image: Image here]

```
var image = './stylesheet/images/map-marker/activity-marker.png';

 for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var coords = data[i].GPSCoordinates.split(',');
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0], coords[1]);
    var labels = "" + (i + 1);
    addMarker(position, map, labels);
 }

 function addMarker(location, map,label) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map,
        label: {
           text: label,
           fontSize: "12px",
           color: "#e74c3c",
           fontFamily: "montserrat"
        },
        icon: image
     });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var image = './stylesheet/images/map-marker/activity-marker.png';

 for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var coords = data[i].GPSCoordinates.split(',');
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0], coords[1]);
    var labels = "" + (i + 1);
    addMarker(position, map, labels);
 }

 function addMarker(location, map,label) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map,
        icon: {
             labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(9, 9),  // Set this value for position of lable on marker...
             url: './stylesheet/images/map-marker/activity-marker.png'
            },
        label: {
           text: label,
           fontSize: "12px",
           color: "#e74c3c",
           fontFamily: "montserrat"
        },
        
     });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

check for a valid  labelOrigin

```
function addMarker(location, map,label) {
   myIcon = {
        url: './stylesheet/images/map-marker/activity-marker.png',
        text: label,
        fontSize: "12px",
        color: "#e74c3c",
        fontFamily: "montserrat"
        size: new google.maps.Size(32, 38),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(32, 38),
        labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(9, 9),
   };
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map,
        icon: myIcon,
     });
  }
```

Comment: what mean "is not working"  have you error in browser  console.?  ..wrong result  ?  .. don't see the marker? .. 
 .. have you tried adgiusting the param ? .. have tried  reloading scripts?